# PDF em ASP.Net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

Preciso exibir um arquivo PDF que estará em meu servidor ou banco (ainda não decidi) numa página Web, feita em ASP.Net C#.

O problema é que esse arquivo tem que ser todo "bloqueado". O usuário não poderá imprimir, fazer download, salvar, copiar text...

Sei que, se o usuário quiser, conseguirá quebrar essas regras, mas preciso dificultar ao máximo.

Comment: Em resumo, você quer salvar este arquivo no formato PDF-A.

Comment: Esses dois artigos talvez possa ajudar, ou esclarecer algumas coisas! - [C# Demo Project of an ASP.NET PDF Viewer Built Based on the GroupDocs.Viewer for .NET Library](http://www.groupdocs.com/blog/asp-net-pdf-viewer-built-based-on-the-groupdocs-viewer-for-net-library) - [Relacionar o item ASP.NET PDF Viewer User Control Without Acrobat Reader Installed on Client or Server](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41933/ASP-NET-PDF-Viewer-User-Control-Without-Acrobat-Re)

Comment: Cigano, não sei o que é o PDF-A. Mas minha ideia não é salvar o arquivo, o usuário vai abrir o arquivo no navegador somente para ler, sem poder fazer mais nenhuma ação sobre ele.